# Need white text on my button instead of the orange I have for links

Tags: html, css

My normal hyperlink color is orange, but I want the hyperlink color in my button to be white and not to be underline. How would I do that?

Also, if I wanted some vertical spacing between the buttons how would I do that?

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/huskydawgs/Uka5v/947/

HTML:

```
<p>Apple is <a href="http://www.apple/com/">cool</a></p>
<a class="btn" href="https://www.apple.com/">Get Started</a>
<a class="orange btn" href="https://www.apple.com/">Get Started</a>
<a class="blue btn" href="https://www.apple.com/">Get Started</a>
```

CSS:

```
.btn {
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background-color: #616161;
    display: block;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 30px;         
    width: 138px;
    margin: 0 auto;
} 

.orange.btn {
    background-color: #f66511;
}

.blue.btn {
    background-color: #2251a4;
}

a:link {
    color:#f66511;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a:visited {
    color:#f66511;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a:active {
    color:#f66511;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover {
    color:#f66511;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer to account for the change in your question. However, keep in mind that follow-up questions are best asked as comments or as a new question entirely :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
.orange.btn {
    background-color: #f66511;
  }

  .blue.btn {
    background-color: #2251a4;
  }
```

(you were missing the "." infront of orange and blue which states the class.

For the vertical spacing, you can use this css:

```
.btn {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Uka5v/940/

Answer (score 1):

You're not defining the variated classes properly. Try this:

```
.btn.orange {
    background-color: #f66511;
}

.btn.blue {
    background-color: #2251a4;
}
```

As for vertical spacing, you can set a bottom margin on the `.btn` class. Since you already have a `margin` property, you can simply add to it:

```
margin: 0 auto 10px; // Added third argument for bottom value
```

Here's the [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uka5v/955/).

**EDIT:** To change the color of the orange button, set a `color` property on the corresponding class:

```
.btn.orange {
    background-color: #f66511;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: For the vertical spacing, what if I wanted to set the top margin?

Comment: Just change the `margin` property to `margin: 10px auto 0;`

Answer (score 0):

change your css to

```
  .orange {
        background-color: #f66511;
      }

      .blue {
        background-color: #2251a4;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use

```
.orange {
    background-color: #f66511;
}

.blue {
    background-color: #2251a4;
}
```

And take a look at margin for adding vertical spacing.

I suggest you brush up on your html knowledge. Try [codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com) for interactive tutorials.